# What is the difference between Tomcat JSSE and APR SSL configuration?

Tags: tomcat

What is general difference? 
Is there any performance loss when using APR?

- Missleading guacamole server example was removed.

Comment: This is about the performance of the UI in general and not the individual remote desktop connections themselves, correct? What makes you think this is due to JSSE vs. APR?

Comment: Correct. I only guessing. I'em new in tomcat. I want to know is there any difference. I think i should ask 2 questions.

Comment: I would try accessing Tomcat via HTTP (no SSL at all) prior to concluding that the SSL implementation is the culprit. Which version of guac?

Comment: There would if anything be a performance *gain*, as APR uses OpenSSL which is native code, but I doubt there would be much in it.